# refresh page after 3 seconds using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I want my code to refresh the page once its shown the success label for 3 seconds.

How can i do this in c# code?

i have this following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.IO;




public partial class CAPTCHA_Contact : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //ImageVerification

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            SetVerificationText();

        }
        imCaptcha.ImageUrl = "captcha.ashx?d=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks;



    }

    public void SetVerificationText()
    {

        Random ran = new Random();

        int no = ran.Next();

        Session["Captcha"] = no.ToString();

    }

    protected void CAPTCHAValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {

        if (Session["Captcha"] != null)
        {

            if (txtVerify.Text != Session["Captcha"].ToString())
            {

                SetVerificationText();

                args.IsValid = false;

                return;

            }

        }

        else
        {

            SetVerificationText();

            args.IsValid = false;

            return;

        }



    }

    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Page.IsValid)
        {

            return;

        }



        SetVerificationText();

        //Save the content
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress(EmailTB.Text);
        mail.To.Add("name@company.co.uk");
        mail.Bcc.Add("test@test.co.uk");
        mail.Subject = "Web Quote";
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Body = "First Name: " + FNameTB.Text + "<br />";
        mail.Body += "Email: " + EmailTB.Text + "<br />";
        mail.Body += "Telephone: " + TelephoneTB.Text + "<br />";
        mail.Body += "Query: " + QueryDD.Text + "<br />";
        mail.Body += "Comments: " + CommentsTB.Text + "<br />";



        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "localhost";
        smtp.Send(mail);

        sucessPH.Visible = true;
    }

      protected void Reset(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        FNameTB.Text = "";
        QueryDD.Text = "";
        EmailTB.Text = "";
        TelephoneTB.Text = "";
        CommentsTB.Text = "";
        txtVerify.Text = "";


    }

    }
```

So after `sucessPH.Visible = true;` i need to count 3 seconds and then refresh the page. This will then clear the form data and the user will also get 3 seconds to see the message to say the message was successfull.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Since this is a client-side concern and not a server-side concern, you'll want to do this with JavaScript.  Keep in mind that by the time the page is sent to the client *all* of the server-side code has completed and disposed.  Trying to do this with server-side code will result in a lot of unnecessary complexity in this case.

In JavaScript you can reload the page with a delay with something like this:

```
setTimeout("window.location.reload()", 3000);
```

Comment: so onsubmit of the form i can set it to reload after 3 seconds?

Comment: my submit button looks like this: <td class = "buttons" colspan="2"><asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSave_Click"/><asp:Button ID="btnReset" runat="server" Text="Reset" OnClick="Reset"/></td>

Comment: @PD24: Do you want it to be 3 seconds after the page reloads, or do you want the user to click a button again afterwards and have it be 3 seconds from that?  It sounds like the former, based on the description.  If that's the case then I wouldn't tie this code to the button at all.  Just output this code to the page when it's being constructed in the click event of the postback.  I'm not sure how WebForms recommends doing this, something about registering client-side script blocks.  But it can even be something as simple as having the code in a literal which is written in the click event.

Comment: i want it 3 seconds after the success message comes up.

Comment: @PD24: Would that be on the rendering of the page after the postback then?  From the point of view of the JavaScript, it doesn't care whether it's a postback or any other .NET code event handler.  As a client-side concern, it's just a matter of the page rendering in the browser in response to the request.  So all you need to do on the server-side is include the JavaScript in the page body of the response when appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you're using webforms, you could use an update panel, and then use the timer component, just like this guy've done

[Tutorial: How to refresh an UpdatePanel control at a timed interval](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400)

Answer (score 1):

Well.. you are in a web.. 
So your server can count 3, but you need the client to count 3 and then postback it to the server...

If your server only counts, then the user will not view anything..

Just make your application ajax enable, and use a timer ;)

This is the code for the page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="3000" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
            </asp:Timer>

        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and in the code behind you have this:

```
  protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do your thing when reach this tick

    }
```

This page will refresh exactly every 3 seconds.

This is .net 4.

Comment: If you give an example of how to do this, then I will upvote your answer.

Comment: The example would be a full page with ajax enable on it?? and throwing an ajax timer control to it? and set the time out to 3000? I don't think I can write an example of something like that ;)...

Comment: How full does the page need to be? But, yes, that's the kind of example I mean.

Comment: thanks but i cannot use .net 4 as the server is only .net 2.0 - 3.5

Answer (score 1):

Right after `sucessPH.Visible = true;` add following line: `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "refresh", "setTimeout('window.location.href=window.location.href', 3000);", true);`