# Asp.Net asynchronous loop not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, asynchronous, async-await

I am attempting to send an image to the browser every 16 ms (~60Hz) from a specific file on the drive which is changing constantly (also at ~60Hz). To do this I am using Response.BinaryWrite(). Below is my code (it really is quite simple)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainLoop();
}

private async Task MainLoop()
{
    while (true)
    {
        //Update image to latest from server
        Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("/Frames/frame.png")));
        Response.Flush();
        await Task.Delay(16);
    }
}
```

My problem is that it does not refresh. I have double and triple checked that the file is indeed changing, and I have also tried updating a label with the current time in milliseconds. I have found that even when doing that, it does not update at all after the page loads.

If I reload the page it displays both a new image, and a new time, so the issue doesn't seem to be in the Response writing. Rather, it's as if the page is simply ignoring the loop entirely, and only running once through.

If anybody has any advice on alternatives to try (keep in mind video is not an option due to the live nature of this) I would be glad to hear them. Perhaps I am missing something very simple here, but I just can't find it!

Thanks!

Comment: The while loop will run indefinitely every 16ms but nothing will ever be sent to the browser. The server will just keep doing that and the request will never end. You need to read about how web request & response works.

Comment: A 60 Hz image == Video.

Comment: Yes, however it is being streamed one frame at a time - from a live server, to a live client. Something like a screensharing tool.

Answer (score 1):

Thoughts on the problem:

1. So the problem is that the page doesn't render updated results every 16ms. We can't solve this issue through server side code (e.g. c# code like your snippet).
2. I'm sure the while loop is still running but you will always need to refresh the page manually since this is ASP.NET (traditional web app with refresh). Here is a stack overflow answer that can back me up (in case you are skeptical about what I'm saying) [refresh page after 3 seconds using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584252/refresh-page-after-3-seconds-using-c-sharp)

I'm not sure what the end goal here is, but I'm assuming you want to render your page with your updated png every 16ms. Basically from my 2 points above, don't resort to trying to update the image through the server side; **instead, look into other options through the client side code** (e.g. javascript).

Of course, I would try to comment further on where you should look exactly, but I never really dealt with updating an image every 16ms before!

I'm just going to throw in some links that could generate some ideas:

1. [Refresh an image in the browser every x milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500244/refresh-an-image-in-the-browser-every-x-milliseconds)
2. [Change image in HTML page every few seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975891/change-image-in-html-page-every-few-seconds)
3. http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/web/realtime.html

I hope this can push you along! Let me know how this goes because I'm curious on how you will do this :)

Comment: Thanks, I have looked into refreshing the page however unfortunately refreshing every 16ms leads to a browser error regarding too many redirects. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

You need to not only get the new image but also ensure the browser does not use the cashed image.

So, there's four steps to the solution:

1. Create a controller action that returns the current image, but your controller action needs to take an argument. The argument becomes a query string parameter. Each time you call the method, the param value should be different. This way,  the browser considers the URL to be new and will not use a cached image. Your url should look something like http://mysite/my controller/getimage?param=12345678927483817
2. Create a JavaScript method to change the SRC property of the image by pointing  it to the URL of your new controller action. Use something that constantly changes for your query parameter. I suggest using the current date time in milliseconds.
3. After the page loads, set a timer in JavaScript to call the function you created in Step 2.
4. Eat a cookie, because cookies are good.

Comment: Nevermind, I just saw your refresh rate needs. My solution will not give you the performance you need. You should be using streaming content instead of an image.

Comment: Haha, yeah I've tried this method already. Will be turning to either streaming or WebRTC. Both are looking very promising. Thanks anyways!